# Vtune get summary information only

Tags: performance, intel, xeon-phi, intel-vtune

I use Intel Vtune to profile a code on Xeon Phi. I use the following command:

`amplxe-cl -collect knc-general-exploration ./a.out`

The result is a bunch of information along with a new directory containing more information. I'm just interested in a metric (say CPI). I do not want Vtune to create a directory with lots of other information.

Is there a command line option to say `just print the summary`